# error C2664: 'cvSaveImage' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'cv::Mat' to 'const CvArr *'

Tags: c++, opencv

I am getting the the following error "cannot convert cv::Mat to constCvArr".Here's the code.

Could anyone help in this case
What is the reason for the error? how could I correct it.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "opencv2\calib3d\calib3d.hpp"
#include <opencv2\core\core.hpp>
#include "opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp"
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace cv;
Mat src_gray;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
char *str1=(char *)malloc(500);
int nums=20;
for(int iter=0;iter<nums;iter++)
{


sprintf(str1,"training1//image%d.png",iter);

Mat img=imread(str1);

cvtColor(img,src_gray,CV_BGR2GRAY);

cv::Mat output = cv::Mat::zeros(img.rows,img.cols,img.type());

threshold(src_gray,output,128,255,THRESH_OTSU | THRESH_BINARY_INV);

char *out=(char *)malloc(500);

sprintf(out,"out%d.png",iter);

cvSaveImage(output,out);

namedWindow("threshold",1);

imshow("threshold",output);

waitKey(0);

return 0;
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you're mixing old , deprecated c-api calls(bad) with the newer c++ api(good).

instead of:

```
 cvSaveImage(output,out);
```

use:

```
 imwrite(output,out);
```

also, whatever you malloc(), you'll have to free ;) (you got 2 memleaks there), again, avoid the whole issue:

```
 Mat img=imread( cv::format("training1/image%d.png",iter) ); // note: *single* slash in path, or *double backslash
 // ...

imwrite( cv::format("out%d.png",iter) );
```

Comment: It is not the answer to the question. cvSaveImage is not written in the proper order cvSaveImage(out,output); and the answer should have explained how to convert Mat to const cvArr*. However I agree that Mat should be used with imwrite.